# How can I transfer ownership of these remaining records?

Tags: ownership

I'm attempting to transfer ownership of records from the old admins' names to my user account and have succeeded using Mass Transfer Records. When I attempt to transfer Price Rules, however, I keep getting the error message "Invalid Input Item or Item Class required" and they won't transfer. What can I do to get the process moving?

Comment: If you can elaborate your question with some example of data or process, then hopefully you will get proper ans

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Item class mandatory field when transferring the price rules . Also check if there is any validation rule for this field.